# How to fix uv with exact dimensions?

Tags: uv

i have a wall 10x10 feet and with the regular way i have uv, smart uv, why need to scale up or down, is there any way or addon that fix the exact size or dimension on the face. why need to manually scale and assume the texture looks good, any other way.any way to make it fix or calculate the dimension and set.

[image]

Comment: Hi :). Yes, you want to keep Texel density the same. You can use addons like Magic UV (shipped with blender i believe)

Comment: @JachymMichal can i get detail comment or answer how it works

Comment: Hi :). There are many answers already on SE and YT videos explaining texel density. I don't have time right now ;)

Comment: @JachymMichal let me search and get you back, Thanks